# Изменение текста, если условие не выполнено

Tags: javascript

Есть `input` и есть условие. Если условие не выполнено, ссылка отключается.
Как сделать так, чтобы изменялся текст ссылки?

```html
<input type="text" name="comment" />
<a id="nhome" href="home.html">Изменить</a>
```

Comment: Добавил в вопрос код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Усовершенствованный вариант.

```js
// input value = '123' -> disable link. 
// input value != '123' -> change link text to smtj
var link = document.getElementById('test');
link.style['margin-left'] = '40px';
document.getElementById('123').addEventListener('input', function() {
  link.style['pointer-events'] = 'initial';
  
  if (/ДА/gi.test(this.value)) {
    link.href = 'yes';
    link.innerText = 'Перейти ->';
link.style['margin-left'] = '0px';
  }else {
  link.removeAttribute('href');
    link.innerText = 'Введите "ДА"';
    link.style['margin-left'] = '40px';
  }  
}, false);
```

```html
<input value='' name='name' id=123>
<a id='test'>Введите "ДА"</a>
```

Comment: мне нужно чтобы текст ссылки изменялся на просто текст, а не на то что ввели...

Comment: Исправил теперь нужно ввести да

Comment: А как седлать чтобы был отступ справа больше когда выводиться "Введите "ДА""?

Comment: В смысле? Через CSS. Объясните что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: может отступ слева?

Comment: ой:) Да слева. У меня текст имеет разную длину и если один текст до изменения скриптом я ставлю по середине, то после изменения текста скриптом текст который длине делиться на две строчки

Comment: Ну вот посмотрите пример, так?

Comment: Да, благодарю. Низкий вам поклон.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// input value = '123' -> disable link. 
// input value != '123' -> change link text to smtj
var link = document.getElementById('test');
document.getElementById('123').onkeyup = function() {
  link.style['pointer-events'] = 'initial';
  link.innerText = this.value;

  if (this.value === '123') {
    link.style['pointer-events'] = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<input value='' name='name' id=123>
<a href='helpme' id='test'>Я ссылка</a>
```

Смотрите код, там все есть

Comment: Вместо `.onkeyup =` рекомендуется использовать `.addEventListener("keyup",`

Comment: А лучше oninput